# python django: error using inline formset

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have the following models:

```
class Equipment(models.Model):
    asset_number = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

class Calibration(models.Model):
    cal_asset = models.ForeignKey(Equipment, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    cal_by = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    cal_date = models.DateField()
    notes = models.TextField(max_length = 200)
```

and view:

```
def default_detail (request, equipment_id):
    equipment = Equipment.objects.get(id = equipment_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if 'calibration' in request.POST:
            EquipmentInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Equipment, Calibration, fields = ('cal_by', 'cal_dates', 'notes')
            formset = EquipmentInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=equipment)
            if formset.is_valid():
                formset.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('calbase:default_detail', args=(post.id)))
    else:
        formset = EquipmentInlineFormSet(instance=equipment)
    return render(request, 'calbase/default_detail.html', {'formset' : formset})
```

and template for this view:

```
<h1>{{ equipment.serial_number }}</h1>

{{equipment.serial_number}} -- {{equipment.asset_number}} <br>


calibration history:
{% for calibrations in equipment.calibration_set.all %}
<ul>
     <li>
         {{calibrations.cal_by}} -- {{calibrations.cal_date}} -- {{calibrations.notes}}
     </li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form method="POST" action = "{% url 'calbase:default_detail' equipment.id %}">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset }}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default" name = "calibration">Save</button>
</form>

<a href="{% url 'calbase:default' %}">Back?</a>
```

This view is simply a detail view of equipment, showing some information (asset and serial # of this piece of equipment). I am trying to add a formset that let user add calibration record to this equipment in this view and display them if any. I learned that using inline formset is probably the way to go. However, after following [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-an-inline-formset-in-a-view) step by step, I am having a

> equipmentInlineFormSet = EquipmentInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=equipment)
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

error even though I checked to make sure that there is no typos or so. I am just trying to figure out what I did wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it a missing closing parenthesis on this line?

```
        EquipmentInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Equipment, Calibration, fields = ('cal_by', 'cal_dates', 'notes')
```